# Why isn't any slash commands working on Minecraft Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My cheats are enabled, and I was using them last night but this morning when I logged in my slash commands are reading "Unknown Command" You must have permission etc.

I do play in the dark at night is there a key on my laptop that I could have hit causing this? I've looked for answers online and tried everything I could think of with no results.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Can you please add some of the commands you use, and the version of Minecraft you are playing on?

Comment: I suspect you either could have pressed the wrong key, accidentally switched the keys in the controls settings or maybe the world allowed cheats before, such as in the case of a LAN world, but now it does not. If you're definitely using the wrong key, you could make the world a LAN world with cheats activated every time you join. However, if it's not a problem with the keys, I wouldn't know how this happened suddenly.

Comment: This is currently a known bug. See the duplicate question for the bug report on Mojang's side

Answer (score 1):

I think you either did one of the following:

- Used the backslash instead of the slash
- Opened to LAN before and forgot to do it again
- Try turning on the lights and carefully typing each key